# Getting Windows NT Kernel Object by Name from within a kernel driver

Tags: c, windows, windows-kernel

I am new to Windows kernel programming. I wonder how I can convert a given
path in the NT kernel namespace (like \Device\HarddiskVolume1) to a kernel object for further usage, if that is possible at all. If there are seperate functions for different object types, I only need the function for the harddisk volumes.

In other words, is there something like:

ObGetObjectByName(wchar_t *name)

I've heard that there are (undocumented) ways to browse the NT kernel namespace from User space, for example used by the WinObj utility. What I need is to access the harddrive object from within a kernel driver.

Comment: for open file object on device you can use `IoCreateFile[Ex]`, `NtOpenFile` or `ZwOpenFile`, `ZwCreateFile` or `NtCreateFile`

Comment: for more general (not only device) you can use `ObOpenObjectByName`

Comment: or `ObReferenceObjectByName` if you need pointer to object, but not handle

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@RbMm already basically answered your question in the comments, but I'll put it here as an answer.

Generally speaking, you want to open the object to get a handle or an object pointer. Depending on the type of object and context will affect how you should to this. For files, `IoCreateFile[Ex]`, `NtOpenFile` or `ZwOpenFile`, `ZwCreateFile`, `NtCreateFile` are examples mentioned by @RbMm, and there is also `FltCreateFile` for mini-filter drivers.

For registry keys you have functions like `ZwCreateKey` or `ZwOpenKey`, etc. The generic and not-documented `ObOpenObjectByName` can open most types of objects, but you really need to specify the object type to prevent getting a pointer to something that won't behave the way you expect. See [ObOpenObjectPointer](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff550985(v=vs.85).aspx) for some additional info on these object types.

Comment: `ObOpenObjectByName` is probably undocumented because of its optional context parameter, which would require documenting too many implementation details. This argument can be required in order to pass create options to the parse procedure of some types (e.g. from `ZwCreateKey` to the Key parse routine, `CmpParseKey`). It's always required by the I/O Manager, for which the context is an open packet for the Device parse routine, `IopParseDevice` -- for create options, disposition, share access, and specific File type (None, NamedPipe, Mailslot) and extra parameters for a given File type.

Answer (score 0):

What I was originally looking for was to get a device object which I can send IRPs to (by IoCallDriver()). I found that IoGetDeviceObjectPointer() does what I need, however it requires the FileObject returned by reference from IoGetDeviceObjectPointer set in the IRPs next stack location (as returned by IoGetNextIrpStackLocation()) (see [Using IRPs for I/O on device object returned by IoGetDeviceObjectPointer()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46749236/using-irps-for-i-o-on-device-object-returned-by-iogetdeviceobjectpointer/46753011#46753011)). Thanks for the help to everybody.

Comment: I should have called the question Getting Windows Device Object from Name instead of Windows Kernel Object ..