# Using IRPs for I/O on device object returned by IoGetDeviceObjectPointer()

Tags: windows, kernel, storage, driver, device

Can one use IoCallDriver() with an IRP created by IoBuildAsynchronousFsdRequest() on a device object returned by IoGetDeviceObjectPointer()? What I have currently fails with blue screen (BSOD) 0x7E (unhandled exception), which when caught shows an Access Violation (0xc0000005). Same code worked when the device was stacked (using the device object returned by IoAttachDeviceToDeviceStack()).

So what I have is about the following:

```
status = IoGetDeviceObjectPointer(&device_name, FILE_ALL_ACCESS, &FileObject, &windows_device);
if (!NT_SUCCESS(status)) {
    return -1;
}
offset.QuadPart = 0;
newIrp = IoBuildAsynchronousFsdRequest(io, windows_device, buffer, 4096, &offset, &io_stat);
if (newIrp == NULL) {
    return -1;
}
IoSetCompletionRoutine(newIrp, DrbdIoCompletion, bio, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE);

status = ObReferenceObjectByPointer(newIrp->Tail.Overlay.Thread, THREAD_ALL_ACCESS, NULL, KernelMode);
if (!NT_SUCCESS(status)) {
    return -1;
}
status = IoCallDriver(bio->bi_bdev->windows_device, newIrp);
if (!NT_SUCCESS(status)) {
    return -1;
}
return 0;
```

device_name is \Device\HarddiskVolume7 which exists according to WinObj.exe .

buffer has enough space and is read/writable. offset and io_stat are on stack (also tried with heap, didn't help). When catching the exception (SEH exception) it doesn't blue screen but shows an access violation as reason for the exception. io is IRP_MJ_READ.

Do I miss something obvious? Is it in general better to use IRPs than the ZwCreateFile / ZwReadFile / ZwWriteFile API (which would be an option, but isn't that slower?)? I also tried a ZwCreateFile to have an extra reference, but this also didn't help.

Thanks for any insights.

Comment: based on your comment i extend answer. how i understand you still make error in your completion (not free Mdl and potential other resources from irp due incorrect `IoFreeIrp` from this place). and your reference/dereference thread still senseless

Comment: Thanks a lot, I actually did free the MDL pages as described on MSDN in the completion routine (and also on errors during creation of the request, I didn't copy paste my original code in the question). About the reference/dereference thread I found this on MSDN: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff548310(v=vs.85).aspx where it says To keep the thread object valid ... . What I am writing is a port of DRBD (distributed replicated block device) from Linux to Microsoft Windows and it is Open Source: please go to https://github.com/LINBIT/wdrbd9 to have a look.

Comment: I will post an update to github in about one or two weeks, so the latest changes are not there yet.

Comment: for case `IoSetHardErrorOrVerifyDevice` yes - exist sense reference/dereference thread object as you do now. but my main idea - instead call `IoFreeIrp` and free *Mdl* (it can be chained some time) and other recourses - `Irp->Tail.Overlay.Thread = KeGetCurrentThread();

    return ContinueCompletion;` so let I/o subsystem do all work

Comment: however for `IoSetHardErrorOrVerifyDevice` better just zero thread `Irp->Tail.Overlay.Thread = 0` after irp create

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you make in this code how minimum 2 critical errors.

1. can I ask - from which file you try read (or write) data ? from
   `FileObject` you say ? but how file system driver, which will handle
   this request know this ? you not pass any file object to `newIrp`.
   look for `IoBuildAsynchronousFsdRequest` - it have no file object
   parameter (and impossible get file object from device object - only
   visa versa - because on device can be multiple files open). so it
   and can not be filled by this api in `newIrp`. you must setup it
   yourself:

   ```
       PIO_STACK_LOCATION irpSp = IoGetNextIrpStackLocation( newIrp );
       irpSp->FileObject = FileObject;
   ```

   I guess bug was exactly when file system try access `FileObject`
   from irp which is 0 in your case. also read docs for
   [`IRP_MJ_READ`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff549327(v=vs.85).aspx) - *IrpSp->FileObject* -
   *Pointer to the file object that is associated with DeviceObject*
2. you pass I guess local variables `io_stat` (and `offset`) to
   `IoBuildAsynchronousFsdRequest`. as result `io_stat` must be valid
   until `newIrp` is completed - I/O subsystem write final result to it
   when operation completed. but you not wait in function until request
   will be completed (in case `STATUS_PENDING` returned) but just exit
   from function. as result later I/O subsystem, if operation completed
   asynchronous, write data to arbitrary address `&io_stat` (it became
   arbitrary just after you exit from function). so you need or check
   for `STATUS_PENDING` returned and wait in this case (have actually
   synchronous io request). but more logical use
   `IoBuildSynchronousFsdRequest` in this case. or allocate `io_stat`
   not from stack, but say in your object which correspond to file. in
   this case you can not have more than single io request with this
   object at time. or if you want exactly asynchronous I/O - you can do
   next trick - `newIrp->UserIosb = &newIrp->IoStatus`. as result you
   iosb always will be valid for `newIrp`. and actual operation status
   you check/use in `DrbdIoCompletion`

also can you explain (not for me - for self) next code line ?:

```
status = ObReferenceObjectByPointer(newIrp->Tail.Overlay.Thread, THREAD_ALL_ACCESS, NULL, KernelMode);
```

who and where dereference thread and what sense in this ?

> Can one use ...

we can use all, but with condition - we understand what we doing and deep understand system internally.

> Is it in general better to use IRPs than the ZwCreateFile / ZwReadFile
>   / ZwWriteFile API

for performance - yes, better. but this require more code and more complex code compare api calls. and require more knowledge. also if you know that previous mode is kernel mode - you can use NtCreateFile, NtWriteFile, NtReadFile - this of course will be bit slow (need every time reference file object by handle) but more faster compare Zw version

---

> Just wanted to add that the `ObReferenceObjectByPointer` is needed
>   because the *IRP* references the current thread which may exit before
>   the request is completed. It is dereferenced in the Completion
>   Routine. Also as a hint the completion routine must return
>   `STATUS_MORE_PROCESSING_REQUIRED` if it frees the *IRP* (took me several
>   days to figure that out).

here you make again several mistakes. how i understand you in completion routine do next:

```
IoFreeIrp(Irp);
return StopCompletion;
```

but call simply call `IoFreeIrp` here is error - resource leak. i advice you check (DbgPrint) `Irp->MdlAddress` at this point. if you read data from file system object and request completed asynchronous - file system always allocate *Mdl* for access user buffer in arbitrary context. now question - who free this *Mdl* ? `IoFreeIrp` - simply free *Irp* memory - nothing more. you do this yourself ? doubt. but *Irp* is complex object, which internally hold many resources. as result need not only free it memory but call "destructor" for it. this "destructor" is `IofCompleteRequest`. when you return `StopCompletion` (`=STATUS_MORE_PROCESSING_REQUIRED`) you break this destructor at very begin. but you must latter again call `IofCompleteRequest` for continue *Irp* (and it resources) correct destroy.

about referencing `Tail.Overlay.Thread` - what you doing - have no sense:

> It is dereferenced in the Completion Routine.

1. but `IofCompleteRequest` access `Tail.Overlay.Thread` **after** it
   call your completion routine (and if you not return
   `StopCompletion`). as result your reference/dereference thread lost
   sense - because you deference it too early, **before** system
   actually access it.
2. also if you return `StopCompletion` and not more call
   `IofCompleteRequest` for this *Irp* - system not access
   `Tail.Overlay.Thread` at all. and you not need reference it in this
   case.
3. and exist else one reason, why reference thread is senseless. system
   access `Tail.Overlay.Thread` only for insert Apc to him - for call
   final part (`IopCompleteRequest`) of Irp destruction in original
   thread context. really this need only for user mode Irp's requests,
   where buffers and *iosb* located in user mode and valid only in
   context of process (original thread ). but if thread is terminated -
   call of `KeInsertQueueApc` **fail** - system not let insert apc to
   died thread. as result `IopCompleteRequest` will be not called and
   resources not freed.

so you or dereference `Tail.Overlay.Thread` too early or you not need do this at all. and reference for died thread anyway not help. in all case what you doing is error.

you can *try* do next here:

```
PETHREAD Thread = Irp->Tail.Overlay.Thread;
IofCompleteRequest(Irp, IO_NO_INCREMENT);// here Thread will be referenced
ObfDereferenceObject(Thread);
return StopCompletion;
```

A [second call](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/kernel/implementing-an-iocompletion-routine) to `IofCompleteRequest` causes the I/O manager to resume calling the IRP's completion. here io manager and access `Tail.Overlay.Thread` insert `Apc` to him. and finally you call `ObfDereferenceObject(Thread);` already **after** system access it and return `StopCompletion` for break first call to `IofCompleteRequest`. look like correct but.. if thread already terminated, how i explain in **3** this will be error, because `KeInsertQueueApc` fail. for extended test - call `IofCallDriver` from separate thread and just exit from it. and in completion run next code:

```
PETHREAD Thread = Irp->Tail.Overlay.Thread;

if (PsIsThreadTerminating(Thread))
{
    DbgPrint("ThreadTerminating\n");

    if (PKAPC Apc = (PKAPC)ExAllocatePool(NonPagedPool, sizeof(KAPC)))
    {
        KeInitializeApc(Apc, Thread, 0, KernelRoutine, 0, 0, KernelMode, 0);

        if (!KeInsertQueueApc(Apc, 0, 0, IO_NO_INCREMENT))
        {
            DbgPrint("!KeInsertQueueApc\n");
            ExFreePool(Apc);
        }
    }
}

PMDL MdlAddress = Irp->MdlAddress;

IofCompleteRequest(Irp, IO_NO_INCREMENT);

ObfDereferenceObject(Thread);

if (MdlAddress == Irp->MdlAddress)
{
    // IopCompleteRequest not called due KeInsertQueueApc fail
    DbgPrint("!!!!!!!!!!!\n");
    IoFreeMdl(MdlAddress);
    IoFreeIrp(Irp);
}

return StopCompletion;

//---------------

VOID KernelRoutine (PKAPC Apc,PKNORMAL_ROUTINE *,PVOID *,PVOID *,PVOID *)
{
    DbgPrint("KernelRoutine(%p)\n", Apc);
    ExFreePool(Apc);
}
```

and you must got next debug output:

```
ThreadTerminating
!KeInsertQueueApc
!!!!!!!!!!!
```

and `KernelRoutine` will be not called (like and `IopCompleteRequest`) - no print from it.

so what is correct solution ? this of course not documented anywhere, but based on deep internal understand. you not need reference original thread. you need do next:

```
  Irp->Tail.Overlay.Thread = KeGetCurrentThread();
  return ContinueCompletion;
```

you can safe change `Tail.Overlay.Thread` - if you have no any pointers valid only in original process context. this is true for kernel mode requests - all your buffers in kernel mode and valid in any context. and of course you not need break Irp destruction but continue it. for correct free mdl and all irp resources. and finally system call `IoFreeIrp` for you.

and again for iosb pointer. how i say pass local variable address, if you exit from function before irp completed (and this iosb accessed) is error. if you break Irp destruction, iosb will be not accessed of course, but in this case much better pass 0 pointer as iosb. (if you latter something change and iosb pointer will be accessed - will be the worst error - arbitrary memory corrupted - with unpredictable effect. and research crash of this will be very-very hard). but if you completion routine - you not need separate iosb at all - you have irp in completion and can direct access it internal iosb - for what you need else one ? so the best solution will be do next:

```
Irp->UserIosb = &Irp->IoStatus;
```

full correct example how read file asynchronous:

```
NTSTATUS DemoCompletion (PDEVICE_OBJECT /*DeviceObject*/, PIRP Irp, BIO* bio)
{
    DbgPrint("DemoCompletion(p=%x mdl=%p)\n", Irp->PendingReturned, Irp->MdlAddress);

    bio->CheckResult(Irp->IoStatus.Status, Irp->IoStatus.Information);
    bio->Release();

    Irp->Tail.Overlay.Thread = KeGetCurrentThread();

    return ContinueCompletion;
}

VOID DoTest (PVOID buf)
{
    PFILE_OBJECT FileObject;
    NTSTATUS status;
    UNICODE_STRING ObjectName = RTL_CONSTANT_STRING(L"\\Device\\HarddiskVolume2");
    OBJECT_ATTRIBUTES oa = { sizeof(oa), 0, &ObjectName, OBJ_CASE_INSENSITIVE };

    if (0 <= (status = GetDeviceObjectPointer(&oa, &FileObject)))
    {
        status = STATUS_INSUFFICIENT_RESOURCES;

        if (BIO* bio = new BIO(FileObject))
        {
            if (buf = bio->AllocBuffer(PAGE_SIZE))
            {
                LARGE_INTEGER ByteOffset = {};

                PDEVICE_OBJECT DeviceObject = IoGetRelatedDeviceObject(FileObject);

                if (PIRP Irp = IoBuildAsynchronousFsdRequest(IRP_MJ_READ, DeviceObject, buf, PAGE_SIZE, &ByteOffset, 0))
                {
                    Irp->UserIosb = &Irp->IoStatus;
                    Irp->Tail.Overlay.Thread = 0;

                    PIO_STACK_LOCATION IrpSp = IoGetNextIrpStackLocation(Irp);

                    IrpSp->FileObject = FileObject;

                    bio->AddRef();

                    IrpSp->CompletionRoutine = (PIO_COMPLETION_ROUTINE)DemoCompletion;
                    IrpSp->Context = bio;
                    IrpSp->Control = SL_INVOKE_ON_CANCEL|SL_INVOKE_ON_ERROR|SL_INVOKE_ON_SUCCESS;

                    status = IofCallDriver(DeviceObject, Irp);
                }
            }

            bio->Release();
        }

        ObfDereferenceObject(FileObject);
    }

    DbgPrint("DoTest=%x\n", status);
}

struct BIO 
{
    PVOID Buffer;
    PFILE_OBJECT FileObject;
    LONG dwRef;

    void AddRef()
    {
        InterlockedIncrement(&dwRef);
    }

    void Release()
    {
        if (!InterlockedDecrement(&dwRef))
        {
            delete this;
        }
    }

    void* operator new(size_t cb)
    {
        return ExAllocatePool(PagedPool, cb);
    }

    void operator delete(void* p)
    {
        ExFreePool(p);
    }

    BIO(PFILE_OBJECT FileObject) : FileObject(FileObject), Buffer(0), dwRef(1)
    {
        DbgPrint("%s<%p>(%p)\n", __FUNCTION__, this, FileObject);

        ObfReferenceObject(FileObject);
    }

    ~BIO()
    {
        if (Buffer)
        {
            ExFreePool(Buffer);
        }

        ObfDereferenceObject(FileObject);

        DbgPrint("%s<%p>(%p)\n", __FUNCTION__, this, FileObject);
    }

    PVOID AllocBuffer(ULONG NumberOfBytes)
    {
        return Buffer = ExAllocatePool(PagedPool, NumberOfBytes);
    }

    void CheckResult(NTSTATUS status, ULONG_PTR Information)
    {
        DbgPrint("CheckResult:status = %x, info = %p\n", status, Information);
        if (0 <= status)
        {
            if (ULONG_PTR cb = min(16, Information))
            {
                char buf[64], *sz = buf;
                PBYTE pb = (PBYTE)Buffer;
                do sz += sprintf(sz, "%02x ", *pb++); while (--cb); sz[-1]= '\n';
                DbgPrint(buf);
            }
        }
    }
};

NTSTATUS GetDeviceObjectPointer(POBJECT_ATTRIBUTES poa, PFILE_OBJECT *FileObject )
{
    HANDLE hFile;
    IO_STATUS_BLOCK iosb;

    NTSTATUS status = IoCreateFile(&hFile, FILE_READ_DATA, poa, &iosb, 0, 0, 
        FILE_SHARE_VALID_FLAGS, FILE_OPEN, FILE_NO_INTERMEDIATE_BUFFERING, 0, 0, CreateFileTypeNone, 0, 0);

    if (0 <= (status))
    {
        status = ObReferenceObjectByHandle(hFile, 0, *IoFileObjectType, KernelMode, (void**)FileObject, 0);
        NtClose(hFile);
    }

    return status;
}
```

and output:

```
BIO::BIO<FFFFC000024D4870>(FFFFE00001BAAB70)
DoTest=103
DemoCompletion(p=1 mdl=FFFFE0000200EE70)
CheckResult:status = 0, info = 0000000000001000
eb 52 90 4e 54 46 53 20 20 20 20 00 02 08 00 00
BIO::~BIO<FFFFC000024D4870>(FFFFE00001BAAB70)
```

the [`eb 52 90 4e 54 46 53`](http://www.ntfs.com/ntfs-partition-boot-sector.htm) read ok

Comment: First of all, setting the FileObject in the IRP stack location solved the blue screen. It seems that some devices (as returned by IoGetDeviceObjectPointer()) are associated with a file object, while others are not (as returned by IoAttchDeviceToDeviceStack). In addition for device control IRPs the File object is also not required (querying the disk geometry with an IRP always worked). Regarding the offset, io_stat parameters I also tried allocating from heap (with ExFreePool), just to let you know that I was aware of Problem #2 in the answer. Now I use memory in the bio (freed in completion)

Comment: Thanks a lot the FileObject really did the trick. Just wanted to add that the ObReferenceObjectByPointer is needed because the IRP references the current thread which may exit before the request is completed. It is dereferenced in the Completion Routine. Also as a hint the completion routine must return STATUS_MORE_PROCESSING_REQUIRED if it frees the IRP (took me several days to figure that out).

Comment: @JohannesThoma - *It seems that some devices (as returned by IoGetDeviceObjectPointer()) are associated with a file object, while others are not (as returned by IoAttchDeviceToDeviceStack)* - this is complete nonsense. look like you not understand base thing. file object created when we open device object. file object have pointer to device. on device can be exist multiple files

Comment: @JohannesThoma - you need ask yourself again - you want read some file - but how device know which file you want read ? you want read from `FileObject` but pass `newIrp` to device where no `FileObject`.

Comment: @JohannesThoma - about *querying the disk geometry with an IRP always worked* - some request can be handled without using file objects, some need file objects - you need look input and output parameters for request in msdn - say [IOCTL_DISK_GET_DRIVE_GEOMETRY](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff560357(v=vs.85).aspx) not require file object, when say [FSCTL_GET_REPARSE_POINT](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff544836(v=vs.85).aspx) require it

Comment: @JohannesThoma - *(freed in completion)* - usually need anyway delete Irp by call `IofCompleRequest`. only this call correct free all resources unlike `IoFreeIrp`. so free iosb even in completion error- because it will be accessed later. you need `newIrp->UserIosb = &newIrp->IoStatus` and not allocate/free any iosb at all